# Angular 2 Inheritance components

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core

I have a basewindow.component which will be the base component for all my components. This basewindow.component will be having buttons like save, delete etc and while clicking "New" button I would like to call basewindow function `ufbNew()` after executing it should execute parent window function `ufNew()`. Please check my code and help me whether I'm doing it correctly. I'm able to call base function but parent not

```
//basewindow.component/// 


import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'basewindow',
    templateUrl: './Basewindow.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./Basewindow.component.css']
})
export class BasewindowComponent {

/////////////////////// User Base Functions ///////////////////

    ufbNew() {

       this.ufNew();
    }
    ufbSave() {
        this.ufSave();
    }

    /////////////////////// User Functions for parent ///////////////////

    ufNew() {
      alert("I m In Base ufbNew")  
    }
    ufSave() {
    }

}


 //// Basewindow.component.html

<div class="container">
    <h1>Hero Form</h1>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group"> 

            <button (click)="ufbNew()">New</button>
            <button (click)="ufbSave()">Save</button> 

        </div>

    </form>
</div>


/////////////////////////// AccountsCategory.Component (Parent 1) ////



import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
import { BasewindowComponent } from '../base/basewindow.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './AccountsCategory.component.html' 
})
export class AccountsCategory extends BasewindowComponent {


   /////////////////////// User Functions for parent ///////////////////
    ufNew() {
      alert("I m in Acounts category (parent)")    
    }
    ufSave() {
    }
}


 //////////// AccountsCategory.component.html /////////////

<basewindow> </basewindow>
```

my purpose is to reuse base component objects , functions and override from child if requires.
please see test application in plnkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/bVxt4GjNXwIg7pDbR4sE?p=preview

Comment: i have added in plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/bVxt4GjNXwIg7pDbR4sE?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
abstract class Animal {
    //OTHER STUFF

    abstract ufSave(): void;

    //OTHER STUFF
}
```

Comment: i have added in plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/bVxt4GjNXwIg7pDbR4sE?p=preview

Comment: my purpose is to reuse base component  objects , functions and override from child if requires, abstract class doesn't work in my case ?

Comment: so basically you want to call the parent method?

Comment: parent then child

Comment: Add super.someMethod() to the beginning of your child  method

Comment: Any luck so far?

Comment: No luck, it seems this feature under development from angualr